# Where to fix Canon lens, other than Canon?

Tags: lens, canon, repair, service-recommendation

I have a 70-200 2.8L II lens that was broken on a photoshoot (dropped 1 ft). The glass is intact (thank you, UV filter) but there is some issue inside the lens where the images aren't focused and the bokeh is weird as if something is misaligned inside.

I know I can send them to Canon but they are slow and expensive, plus my lens is out of warranty so it wouldn't be cheaper to use Canon.

Are there some well-respected places **in the US** where I can send the lens for repair?

Comment: If you are a professional, have you considered CPS membership?  That will speed your service and decease the cost considerably if you own sufficient gear (of which a 70-200f/2.8 IS II is a significant start towards).

Comment: I'm not a professional but I do own a sizable lens collection. I've never had to have anything repaired, it doesn't seem like it would be worth paying for membership. Do you have CPS membership and related experience to provide advice?

Comment: If you are sending stuff in for repair, it's probably worth it for the discount on the repair alone.  You also get expedited processing and several free cleanings.  Technically you have to be a professional to join, though I don't know that they actually check as long as you own enough gear to qualify.

Comment: Also, the 70-200 2.8L IS II is a pretty hard lens to service (lots of elements, IS group, weather-sealed). I wouldn't necessarily trust a third party shop to get it right, not on lenses of that much complexity and cost.

Comment: This question is very location-dependent.  Which country are you in, which state, etc?

Comment: FWIW, Canon is *fast* and expensive. My experience in the last couple of years is that their turnaround time is getting very good. (From the US). For a repair like that, the Canon factory is the only way to go. Send it in, pay the bill, they send it back good as new and with a warranty. And don't feel too bad, sooner or later we all drop something expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It really all depends on where you are. I would avoid using a camera retailer, because they usually send the gear to the manufacturer. If you're anywhere near Michigan, I'd recommend either Oakland Photographic Repair or Midwest Camera Repair. Midwest **RARELY** ships gear to other facilities, and they do repairs in a timely manner.

Oakland Photographic Repair
30575 Dequindre Road
Madison Heights, MI 48071
248-588-1151

Midwest Camera Repair
318 Oak St
Wyandotte, MI 48192
http://www.midwestcamera.com/
734-285-2220